# WCF REST Services - Generic exception handling

Tags: .net, wcf, rest

I have a lot of legacy code that is now a backend for a WCF REST service - it used to be a usual WCF service backend before, if that matters. I want to implement a mechanism that would catch any exception in any method and analyze it. If it turns out to be a known error, it will be processed and turned into a friendly-looking fault.

I know that I can throw `FaultException` or `WebProtocolException` instead of 'usual' exceptions, but there are lots of places where exceptions are thrown all over the code, and looking for all of them is quite a painful option.

I tried to add an endpoint behavior extension that creates a new behavior which overrides standard `WebHttpBehavior.AddServerErrorHandlers` method and adds my error handlers (`IErrorHandler` implementations) to the endpoint dispatcher error handlers collection. Inside the error handlers I analyze the exception and create (or do not create) a desired fault basing on this exception.

I expected this mechanism to return custom data for any known exception, but I was wrong. Good old Microsoft has implemented a wonderful inevitable `WebHttpBehavior2`, which unconditionally adds an internal `Microsoft.ServiceModel.Web.WebErrorHandler` into the end of endpoint dispatcher error handlers collection. This handler ignores all previously executed handlers and recognizes only a small set of exceptions, while the majority is interpreted as "Internal Server Error", and nothing more.

The question is whether I am on a right path and there is a way to disable this handler in WCF REST mechanism, or introduce it with a new Exception (e.g., when any exception is caught, it is first processed by my handlers and if they throw/return, for instance, FaultException, then this new exception is supplied to `Microsoft.ServiceModel.Web.WebErrorHandler` instead of the original one). If all my experiments with `IErrorHandler` and behavior extensions are worthless, what is an alternative? Again, I really do not want to modify the exception throwing logic, I want one place to catch the exceptions and process them.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you change the WCF SOAP services to REST, the whole mindset of error reporting and handling changes.

In SOAP, faults are part of your contract. In REST, they simply become codes that you output in the HTTP response code and description.

Here is a catch snippet:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    Trace.WriteLine(e.ToString());

    OutgoingWebResponseContext response = WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse;
    response.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType; // or anything you want
    response.StatusDescription = e.Message;
    return null; // I was returning a class
}
```

So I would suggest you create a helper code which creates relevant error codes for you and put in the response.

Comment: Such catch should be added to every service method, right? Or is there a way to write it somewhere just once to handle all exceptions? I liked the behavior-based approach because it defined a common handler for all exceptions, and I did not have to worry about handling and processing exceptions for each single method. The best thing is that I defined one processor for all services in the endpoint. I cannot achieve this using your approach, can I?

Comment: Setting the `StatusDescription` has no effect! The response always has generic status description. Is there anyway to fix it?

Comment: It has. You can check that in the outgoing message from the server using fiddler, .... But what you tend to find is that various browsers or different implementations might ignore the description and just use the code to map to a predefined message. I had that issue with an Android app I was making and I ended up setting the description as well as changing the method signature so that I can return a string. Yikes! **That is why I would never ever use WCF REST anymore.**

Comment: @Aliostad did you ever consider returning a custom response HEADER value for the StatusMessage?  I don't see how it is WCF's fault that the client doesn't respect the values being set for StatusDescription?  Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Not really. This will be anti-HTTP. Status code is status code although you can have custom codes, e.g. 909 "My Custom Status".

Comment: Is there a way to get the StatusDescription back to the client?  I'm having the same problem as Hemant.

Answer (score 2):

This what I did in the past

```
    public class MyServerBehavior : IServiceBehavior {

        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription,
             ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, 
             Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, 
             BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters) {

        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription,
                                          ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase) {

            foreach (ChannelDispatcher chDisp in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers) {
                chDisp.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;
                if (chDisp.ErrorHandlers.Count > 0) {
                    // Remove the System.ServiceModel.Web errorHandler
                    chDisp.ErrorHandlers.Remove(chDisp.ErrorHandlers[0]);  
                }
                // Add new custom error handler
                chDisp.ErrorHandlers.Add(new MyErrorHandler());

            }

        }

        public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, 
                             ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase) {
        }

    }
```

MyErrorHandler was my class that implemented IErrorHandler.

Comment: This looks very similar to what I did. Did it work for REST service, or just for SOAP? If it worked for REST service, how did you configure the service? If just for SOAP, then thank you, but REST is a completely different story, as far as I see it now.

Comment: @Michael I did it for REST services.  I was self-hosted and actually created my own derived service host that setup the behavior.  It's all code based, no XML.

Comment: Self-hosted, I see... That's what I was thinking about but considered to be too complicated. Thanks!